# Python Iterate data under grouped / pivot table excel rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pivot-table, openpyxl

I have an excel spreadsheet with pivot table data in it.  The rows are grouped with items under them.  Im not an expert in excel pivot tables so not sure about the formatting of this, but i am trying to read the data via python and convert it to a dictonary to work with.  I cannot find a way to read the data under the grouped rows.  I have tried to iterate the rows with pandas.read_excel and openpyxl but i can only view the title of the grouped rows.  Here is an example screenshot of the excel sheet.

[image: excelsheet]

Comment: The grouping is defined in the Pivot Table Definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Title and Item are in the same column that makes it difficult to separate.
A solution with just Openpyxl can be achieved.
This uses the indent to separate the sections to create a dictionary of dictionaries.
I didn't include the Totals for the Title e.g. `Title1: 2` from the table. Those can be added as another item to the dictionary as you go if it's needed. However I included the Totals by summing the values in the display output.

Code Sample;

```
import openpyxl

pviotfile = 'pivTable.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(pviotfile)
ws = wb.active

ptable_dict = {}
current_title = ''
int_dict = {}
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=5, max_col=1):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.alignment.indent == float(0.0):
            if current_title != '':
                ptable_dict[current_title] = int_dict
                int_dict = {}
            current_title = cell.value
        elif cell.alignment.indent == float(1.0):
            int_dict[cell.value] = cell.offset(column=1).value

for k, v in ptable_dict.items():
    print(f"{k} Totals: {sum(v.values())}")
    for x, y in v.items():
        print(f"{x} {y}")
    print("-------------------")
```

The dictionary is like this;

```
{
'Title1': {'Item1': 1, 'Item2': 1}, 
'Title2': {'Item1': 1, 'Item2': 1, 'Item3': 1, 'Item4': 1, 'Item5': 1, 'Item6': 1, 'Item7': 1, 'Item8': 1}, 
'Title3': {'Item1': 1, 'Item2': 1, 'Item3': 1, 'Item4': 1, 'Item5': 1, 'Item6': 1, 'Item7': 1, 'Item8': 1}, 
'Title4': {'Item1': 1, 'Item2': 1}
}
```

Example display

```
Title1 Totals: 2
Item1 1
Item2 1
-------------------
Title2 Totals: 8
Item1 1
Item2 1
Item3 1
Item4 1
Item5 1
Item6 1
Item7 1
Item8 1
-------------------
Title3 Totals: 8
Item1 1
Item2 1
Item3 1
...
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  The totals next to the item is a nice touch.  For me though when I ran it I still only got the titles back.  I had been able to do this when i was testing but never got the details under them.  Something i guess i was not taking into account was that when I initially access the worksheet, all the groups are collapsed.  I tried your code again after expanding some of the rows and yeah it returned exactly like you said it would.  Is there a way with openpyxl to change the formatting first i guess?  expanding all the collapsed groupings?

Comment: Was able to expand the pivot tables prior to opening with openpyxl using win32com with excel.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a means to expand the table with Openpyxl. As you found this can be done with win32com, it also can be done with Xlwings. Xlwings can also extract the data so if you were going to use Xlwings at all you may as well do the whole job in Xlwings. Xlwings can also read the pivot table as an object.

Comment: One thing I do with single row columns is `cell = row[0]`. Cutting out the second loop makes things a bit easier to read. Also: `Totals` != `Count` . `len(v)` would be more accurate.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I will look into doing it with xlwings to avoid needing to access it twice.